# align environment isn't centered with lualatex?

Tags: xetex, luatex, right-to-left

This is a follow-up question to my previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/683525/witharrows-package-reverses-text-in-rtl-language) where I encountered an issue with `tikz` arrows (specifically with the `witharrows` package which uses `tikz`) combined with `polyglossia` and `xelatex` where the text next to the arrows was generated in LTR fashion despite the document being configured for the Hebrew language (an RTL language) resulting in reversed text.

One user suggested in a comment that the issue is related to the compiler `xelatex` since he got no issues when compiling with `lualatex`. I tried to switch compilers and it indeed solved the problem and the text was rendered correctly. However, a new problem arose which I'd like help solving.

Whenever I used a regular `align*` environment from `amsmath` with `lualatex` it printed on the right side of the page instead of the center like most math equations. Here are pictures of the output of the **same** code compiled once with `xelatex`:
[image]

and once with `lualatex`:
[image]
As you can see, with `xelatex` I get the problem described in my previous question where Hebrew text is reversed next to the arrow in the `DispWithArrows*` environment, while with `lualatex` the contents of a regular `align*` environment are right-aligned instead of centered.

Why does `align*` behave differently with `lualatex` and how can I center it like normal?
Are there other noticeable differences between `xelatex` and `lualatex` regarding the **output** of the code, especially with an RTL document, that I should be aware of?
I've been using `xelatex` until now and I'm considering switching to `lualatex` after this experience. I also heard (correct me if I'm wrong) that `lualatex` is built on top of `pdflatex` so it should behave similarly to it, which is what most people who don't deal with non-English documents use if I am not mistaken.

The code producing the above pictures:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = he_HE
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{witharrows}

% Font and language settings
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[
    Script=Hebrew,
    ItalicFont=*-Regular,
    ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.3},
]{Assistant}

\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setsansfont{Assistant}
\setmonofont{Assistant}

\WithArrowsOptions{displaystyle}
\tikzset{
    WithArrows/arrow/.append style = {
        font = \selectlanguage{hebrew},
    }
}

\begin{document}
דוגמה לחישוב:
\begin{DispWithArrows*}
A &= (a + b)^2 \Arrow{נפתח את הסוגריים בביטוי} \\
&= a^2 + 2ab + b^2
\end{DispWithArrows*}
דוגמה נוספת:
\begin{align*}
A &= (a + b)^2\\
&= a^2 + 2ab + b^2
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I am using the font [Assistant](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Assistant).

Comment: See [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671554/the-alignat-environment-doesnt-center-its-equations-in-a-hebrew-document-who). Maybe babel is now fixing that, I need to check.

Comment: Sadly, I had no time to address this particular issue, but the workaround provided in that link works for me. I hope I can resume the work on `amsmath`.